# Input binding in v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to bind values from input radio button generated by v-for.

I have tried use v-model to bind them with variables `question_1, question_2, question_3` in data().

```vue
<template>
    <div id="radioButtons">
        <div v-for="(question_obj, index) in questions" :key="index" class="form-group form-radio">
            <span>{{ question_obj.question }} {{ question_obj.variable }}</span>
            <br>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" :name="question_obj.variable" v-model="question_obj.variable" value="yes" >
                <span>Yes</span>
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" :name="question_obj.variable" v-model="question_obj.variable" value="no" >
                <span>No</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        name: 'radioButtons',
        data () {
            return {
                question_1: '',
                question_2: '',
                question_3: '',
                questions: [
                    { question: 'Question 1', variable: 'question_1'},
                    { question: 'Question 2', variable: 'question_2'},
                    { question: 'Question 3', variable: 'question_3'},
                ]
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I would like the value to be saved in data () after selecting the radio button.

Answer (score 0):

Use index in `v-for` for v-model changes so it changes question object properties, not their instance:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
      return {
      //question_1: '', //don't need question_1, 2 and 3
     // question_2: '',
     // question_3: '',
      questions: [
        { question: 'Question 1', variable: 'no'}, //notice that I have stored default values in question. Also consider renaming variable to answer to preserve good semantics. 
        { question: 'Question 2', variable: 'yes'},
        { question: 'Question 3', variable: 'no'},
      ]
    }
  },
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>



<div id="app">
 <div id="radioButtons">
    <div v-for="(question_obj, index) in questions" :key="index" class="form-group form-radio">
      <span>{{ question_obj.question }} {{ question_obj.variable }}</span>
      <br>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" :name="'question-' + index" v-model="questions[index].variable" value="yes" :checked="question_obj.variable == 'yes'">
        <span>Yes</span>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" :name="'question-' + index" v-model="questions[index].variable" value="no" :checked="question_obj.variable == 'no'">
        <span>No</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

**Note:** There is no need to store answers in question_1, question_2, question_3, since you might have more than 3 questions, and it won't be efficient. 
Better way is to store answer in variable property value.

So in component it will look like this:

```
<template>
    <div id="radioButtons">
        <div v-for="(question_obj, index) in questions" :key="index" class="form-group form-radio">
            <span>{{ question_obj.question }} {{ question_obj.variable }}</span>
            <br>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" :name="'question-' + index" v-model="questions[index].variable" value="yes" :checked="question_obj.variable == 'yes'">
                <span>Yes</span>
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" :name="'question-' + index" v-model="questions[index].variable" value="no" :checked="question_obj.variable == 'no'">
                <span>No</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        name: 'radioButtons',
        data () {
            return {
                //question_1: '', //don't need question_1, 2 and 3
                // question_2: '',
                // question_3: '',
                questions: [
                    { question: 'Question 1', variable: 'no'}, //notice that I have stored default values in question. Also consider renaming variable to answer to preserve good semantics.
                    { question: 'Question 2', variable: 'yes'},
                    { question: 'Question 3', variable: 'no'},
                ]
            }
        },
    }

</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the values in the vue-tool aren't changed.

Comment: @neuroine, run the code snippet, and you will see it changes the values for each item under questions. I have commented question_1, question_2, and question_3,  since it is necessary and not efficient in case you will have more than 3 question. What about 1000 questions? Will you set new models for answer for each of these?

Comment: actual change occurs for each variable property value under the questions object

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```js
export default {
  name: 'radioButtons',
  data () {
      return {
      radio_data: {
        'question_1': '',
        'question_2': '',
        'question_3': ''
      },
      questions: [
          { question: 'Question 1', variable: 'question_1'},
          { question: 'Question 2', variable: 'question_2'},
          { question: 'Question 3', variable: 'question_3'}
      ]
    }
  },
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div id="radioButtons">
  <div v-for="(question_obj, index) in questions" :key="index" class="form-group form-radio">
    <span>{{ question_obj.question }} {{ question_obj.variable }}</span>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" :name="'question-' + index" v-model="radio_data[questions[index].variable]" value="yes" :checked="question_obj.variable == 'yes'">
      <span>Yes</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" :name="'question-' + index" v-model="radio_data[questions[index].variable]" value="no" :checked="question_obj.variable == 'no'">
      <span>No</span>
  </label>
  </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your key, question, and answer in the same object in your array of questions. If you want to get the selected values as an object, use a method to reduce them into an appropriate value. In the example code below I've included such a method, as well as live JSON output to see the result.

```vue
<template>
    <div id="radioButtons">
        <div
            v-for="row in questions"
            :key="row.key"
            class="form-group form-radio"
        >
            <span>{{ row.question }} {{ row.key }}</span>
            <br />
            <label>
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    :name="row.key"
                    v-model="row.answer"
                    value="yes"
                />
                <span>Yes</span>
            </label>
            <label>
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    :name="row.key"
                    v-model="row.answer"
                    value="no"
                />
                <span>No</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <pre>{{ JSON.stringify(getAnswers(), null, 2) }}</pre>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "radioButtons",
        data() {
            return {
                questions: [
                    { key: "question_1", question: "Question 1", answer: null },
                    { key: "question_2", question: "Question 2", answer: null },
                    { key: "question_3", question: "Question 3", answer: null },
                ],
            };
        },
        methods: {
            getAnswers() {
                return this.questions.reduce((acc, cur) => {
                    acc[cur.key] = cur.answer;
                    return acc;
                }, {});
            },
        },
    };
</script>
```